# How can I make foggy, uneven liquid with clumps?

Tags: materials

I'm trying to render a barrel with an opening on one side to view inside, but I want the liquid inside the barrel to be sort of "uneven", kind of like how fog looks, with "clumps" here and there: like it's being mixed unevenly and has various thicknesses.

I'm hitting a wall trying to google it as I come up against only stuff like viscosity and thickness. 
It's not an animated render, just a render of a barrel with an opening on one side and liquid inside.

I've added a [WIP](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/WIP#Noun) of my render (it's from an old game called [Blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_(video_game))).

[image]

Comment: Hi, VirtualForce. I edited the title so it's more descriptive. Hopefully, it will help people know what the question is about just by looking at it in a question list and also it will be easier to find for people who might be searching the web with similar questions in the future. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Hi, no problem at all! Appreciate all the help I can get!
Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Use a noise texture as the density input for the volume.

[image: node seutp]

The noise texture's output values are in the range $[0, 1]$, but most noise values are closer to $0.5$. Setting the *From Min/Max* values to something around 0.5 (e.g. $[0.3,0.54]$) increase the contrast in the noise. That way there are less voxels with $0.5$ density and more with $0$ or $1$ density. The *To Max* value of 3 just moves the maximum density to 3. This slider can be used to control the overall density and fit the liquid to the scale of the model.

Comment: Could somebody elaborate on the map range settings here as to why these numbers are chosen?

Comment: @Glenp Does the last paragraph help?